# Como hago el efecto smooth scroll con javascript nativo

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Queria poner el efecto smoth scroll en mi pagina, estaba usando la libreria smoth scrolling pero me genero problema con un acordion, se me desplazaba hacia abajo cada vez que lo cerraba.

este es el codigo de la libreria

```
Smooth Scrolling

document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
});
```

este es el acordion

```
<section id="faq" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Preguntas Frecuentes</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="contenedor">
                <div id="fag1">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <a href="#uno" class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#fag1">¿Son seguras nuestras cuentas?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="uno" class="collapse hide">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Todas nuestras cuentas son totalmente seguras y confiables
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: El problema está en que el `anchor` que usas para cerrar el `accordion` tendrá un href que coincide con ese selector `href="#...."` entonces esto ejecuta el smooth scrolling. Podrías excluir al `accordion` por clase de ese selector con algo así: `.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]:not(.accordionClass)')`

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://medium.com/@gurjitmehta/smooth-scroll-with-javascript-571283e9a3cd

Answer (score 1):

Si tu usas jquery sería más fácil hacer el scroll down. Te lo dejaré en jquery y en javascrip para que veas la diferencia.

He puesto en ambos códigos comentarios para que entiendas como funciona el proceso

**Jquery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event){
    //Aquí elimina el evento normal de la etiqueta <a>
    event.preventDefault();
    //Aquí cojemos el elmento
    var elem=$(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(elem).offset().top
    },800);
  });
});
```

```css
.separador{
   height:500px;
}
#abc{
  background:red;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#abc">dfas</a>
<div class="separador"></div>
<div id="abc"></div>
<div class="separador"></div>
```

**Javascript puro:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    //Eliminamos el evento
    e.preventDefault();
    //Cojemos el nombre del id
    var id_attr=this.getAttribute('href').substring(1);
    //Activamos la función de scroll cojiendo la posición 
    //más alta del elemento (offsetTop)
    scrollPosicion(document.getElementById(id_attr).offsetTop, 9);
});
function scrollPosicion(pos, tiempo){
  //cojemos la posición actual
  var actualpos=window.scrollY||window.screenTop;
  //comprobamos si el elemento esta hacia arriba o hacia abajo
  if(actualpos<pos){
    //comprobamos si hay un tiempo establecido
    if(tiempo){
      var x;
      var i=actualpos;
      //Creamos el intervalo para que vaya bajando poco a poco
      x=setInterval(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0,i);
        i+=10;
        if(i>=pos){
          clearInterval(x);
        }
      },tiempo);
    }else{
      var t=10;
      //Si no existe el tiempo establecido. Creamos un bucle
      //en vez de un intervalo para mayor facilidad con las 
      //variables
      for(let i = actualpos; i<=pos; i+=10){
        t+=10;
        setTimeout(function(){
          window.scrollTo(0,i);
        },t/2)
      }
    }
  }else{
    //Si no esta establecido tiempo, se establece en 2
    tiempo=tiempo || 2;
    var i=actualpos;
    var x;
    //Intervalo para ir bajando poco a poco
    x=setInterval(function(){
      window.scrollTo(0,i);
      i-=10;
      if(i<=pos){
        clearInterval(x);
      }
    },tiempo);
  }
}
```

```css
.separador{
   height:500px;
}
#abc{
  background:red;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#abc">dfas</a>
<div class="separador"></div>
<div id="abc"></div>
<div class="separador"></div>
```